# Restoring folder and files from Backblaze using Cloudberry

Tags: linux, backup, restore, cloudberry

I'm investigating alternative solutions to Crashplan. Currently I have Crashplan running headless on my Netgear NAS (ReadyNasOS 6.8).
I have installed Cloudberry (free version, 200GB datalimit) which is taking backups to BackBlaze B2 Cloud Storage (also a free account, as it is for testing only right now).

I have created a backup plan which backs up a testing folder to B2 Cloud Storage. This plan seems to be running just fine.

The only thing I don't seem to get working is the restore plan. I would like to restore a folder with some files in it but it doesnt work. The restore only needs to run once. I have deliberately deleted the folder on my NAS.

The backup job looks like this: ./cbb addRestorePlan -n "RestoreTask" -a "B2" -sy no -f "/data/Documenten/TESTMAP/20170723_Fotos/" -se yes -ol yes

I run the task manually once it is created: ./cbb plan -r "RestoreTask"

The files are located at: Buckets / nas-ea-94-93 / CBB_nas-EA-93-94 / CBB_VOLUMES / 33ea9394:data / Documenten / TESTMAP / 20170723_Fotos

The files are located on my NAS at /data/Documenten/TESTMAP/20170723_Fotos

If I would get any output from Cloudberry, that would also be very handy

---

I have deleted the folder from the source (my nas device) which I'm backing up to the B2 Cloud using cloudberry.

I think that this is the most realistic scenario (= accidentally deleting files from my NAS device, as this is my 'work' storage device).

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you have deleted the data from your backup destination? If so, could you initiate the repo synchronization? If it's Linux backup, issue the command ./cbb account -sync "your_accountname"

Once it's done - try to initiate the restore one more time